# cakephp - session variable keeps acting strangely

Tags: cakephp, session-variables

For reasons that elude me, a session variable that contains the customer's name will show up for a short while, and then disappear.

In the app_controller.php : beforeFilter()

```
if (isset($_SESSION['customer_name']) == false  || 
    strlen($_SESSION['customer_name']) == 0)
{
  $customer = $this->Customer->read(null, $auth['User']['customer_id']);
  $name = $customer['Customer']['fname'] . " " . $customer['Customer']['lname'];
  $this->Session->write('customer_name', $name);
  $this->set('name', $this->Session->read('customer_name'));
}
else
{
  $this->set('name', $this->Session->read('customer_name'));
}
```

I have tried variations on checking to see if the session is set such as

```
if ($this->Session->check('customer_name') == false)
```

Everything behaves in the same bizarre way, it will display in the view for a little while, and then disappear. Doesn't come back on closing browser or logging in again. Random small changes to that code seem to bring it back to life for a short time.

Comment: My answer was the answer to the problem I was experiencing, I am just waiting for StackOverflow to allow me to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$name = $customer['Customer']['fname'] . " " . $customer['Customer']['lname'];
```

Allows $name to equal " ", which means it has a strlen of 1, and is not empty. Not sure why it didn't get the customer data, but now I can check for that value.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$this->Session->read()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/398/Methods#read-401) instead of direct $_SESSION calls as cakephp can be storing the session somewhere else that where native PHP is expecting it.

Also, I don't really understand what you mean by 'disappear for a little while', if you stay on the same page and just keep hitting refresh does it show/dissapear randomly ?

Closing the browser could very well be the reason fot your session to be destroyed, also do you experience that behavior on different browsers ?

What are your `Session.*` sessings in app/config/core.php ?

Comment: originally I used read and check from the Session helper, but as things became more random I abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

This solved our problem:

`if($this->Session->check('customer_name'))`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the problem is, but I'd start by removing $_SESSION calls. I'd also change

```
strlen($_SESSION['customer_name']) == 0
```

to

```
empty($_SESSION['customer_name'])
```

The only other thing I can think of is lowering your security level in /config/core.php, maybe you're losing session entirely?

Answer (score 0):

normally the session will expire after a few minutes in cake. Look for this line in the config/core.php file:

> Configure::write('Session.timeout'

and set it to like 999999999. That should solve the problem.

Comment: According to the comments in core.php Session.timeout isn't used if you are using the Session.security setting. which mine is set to high.

Comment: Session.timeout is used always, as a multiplier. See comment above Security.level in core.php and you'll see the math.

Answer (score 0):

Note that sometimes FireFox extensions can cause session resets.  Any time the User-Agent changes, the Session is reset.

I ran into this problem recently using a FireBug extension called FirePHP :
http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/cakephp-session-error-user-agent-must-be-consistent